# core-plot, how to make axes titles floating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plot, core-plot

I'm working with core-plot and want to know if it's possible to make the axes titles floating, like we can do with axes. I use it for the y axe, and it works fine, it doesn't move when I scroll.
Here the code for the Y axe:

```
y.isFloatingAxis = YES;
```

I just want the title doesn't move on scrolling.

Or a tips if there's no option.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the `titleLocation` property to NaN (the default value), the title will stay centered in the plot range as the plot scrolls. If you want it to stay fixed in another location, you can use a plot space delegate to update the title location to the desired location when scrolling.

Comment: oO it was that simple, I knew it would be something like that, thx.